# Can two or more Route render the same component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a situation:

```
 <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
 <Route path="/users/:id" component={Home}/>
```

However when switching the paths, im getting re-rendered a lot of components.

Question: is it okey that two or more Route renders the same component? Or should I change it?

Comment: It's alright. Maybe you could split the `Home` component into smaller components or have the `/users/:id` route inside `Home`, but what you have now is not necessarily wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - absolutely. I use this all the time... if you have the same exact component... Home... it doesn't make sense to break it up into smaller components. It's the same thing. That just makes things confusing. If you're using react-router 4 then you can use regex patterns instead if you'd like.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/391